# Extending a base class that has modes of operation

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a C++ `class Axis` describing a motion axis, which operates in one of several modes, represented today by the data member `mode` of an enum type. a `run_step()` member function runs periodically and performs control actions that depend on `mode` (`run_step()` is essentially a switch-case statement).

Now I need to refactor this class into two classes, a `BasicAxis` that supports a subset of the modes and represents a motion axis with less physical capabilities (e.g. doesn't have some types of sensors) and an `ExtendedAxis` that supports the full functionality as in my `Axis` class today. I think it would be natural to have `ExtendedAxis` inherit from `BasicAxis`. However, some complications arise (and they are my questions):

1. **How should I represent the current mode of operation** now, while ideally still keeping type safety? I should clarify that each object (of either type) is at **exactly one mode at any given time**: the mode can be any of the basic modes for a BasicAxis object, and any of the basic OR extended modes for an ExtendedAxis object.
2. **How should I separate the implementation of `run_step()`'s code** into the two classes? `BasicAxis` should have code that handles basic modes, and ideally know nothing about the extended modes. `ExtendedAxis` should only implement the code handling extended modes.

I went over several implementation ideas and nothing feels like a clean, good design - so I would happy to hear your thoughts of how to implement this.

---

**Edit 2:** shortened and cleaned up the question.

---

**Edit 1:**

I'm adding a simplistic code example to explain the issue better.

**Situation today:**
This class represents an axis that does have all extended features, and cannot represent a more basic axis:

```
class Axis
{
    enum Mode {BASIC_MODE_1, BASIC_MODE_2, EXT_MODE_1, EXT_MODE_2};
    Mode mode;
    void run_step();
    // ... and lots of Extended-related stuff here too 
};

Axis::run_step()
{
    switch(mode)
    {
    case BASIC_MODE_1:
        // Mode 1 control operations
        break;
    // same for other modes...
    
    case EXT_MODE_1;
        // Extended modes are also here today (not good)
        break;
    }
}
```

Sketch of an approach for separation into a `BasicAxis` and an `ExtendedAxis`. It still written with an enum and a switch block for illustration, but they very well may not be suitable anymore. Can you suggest something better?

```
class BasicAxis
{
    WhatTypeHere mode; // how and where to represent the mode now?
    // this object can only be in one of the BASIC_MODE_x modes
    // it's not even supposed to know about the extended modes
    void run_step();
    void run_extended() {} // just an idea, maybe needs a different approach
};

BaseAxis::run_step()
{
    switch(mode)  // or perhaps not a switch? depends on the new representation of mode
    {
    case BASIC_MODE_1:
        // Mode 1 actions
        break;
    // ...other basic modes...
    // no extended modes here anymore
    default: // we're probably currently in an extended mode
        run_extended(); // ?? or some other way to divide control between Base and Extended classes
    }
}

class ExtendedAxis : public BasicAxis
{
    // extends the modes somehow
    // this object can be in either BASIC_MODE_x or EXTENDED_MODE_x modes, like the first example
    
    virtual void run_extended() {/* what's here? */}
    // other, extended-specific members go here
};

class AdvancedAxis : public BasicAxis
{
    // maybe there will be additional derived classes from BasicAxis in the future
    // they would support BasicAxis's modes and also add modes of their own
};
```

Comment: While I cannot say I fully understand the problem description (could you post some meaningful but small example to illustrate it?), whenever I hear of enums being used to implement mode with switch cases I recommend to look at Strategy or Template Method patterns.

Comment: thanks, I added a code example. I will take a look at the Strategy and Template Method patterns. I would guess they only relate to the second part of how to divide implementation between the BasicAxis and ExtendedAxis - I also am not sure how to represent the current mode itself now that there are both basic modes and extended modes (and maybe later also Advanced modes and Whatever modes etc etc)

Comment: Is this a no `std` environment?

Comment: While it is an embedded environment without an OS, I do use some std stuff. However I am reluctant to use dynamic memory allocation and only use the STL (Vector, Map etc) where other options are really ugly. Specifically, these classes need to be able to be statically-allocated.

Answer (score 1):

What if you abstracted out the functionality of each mode into a separate `struct`. Each `struct` is then a unique type that not only represents the "mode" but also the modes functionality.

You can then store the current "mode" in a `std::variant`.
Both the basic and extended axes `class`es supply the base axis with the modes that each support.

The visitor pattern can then be used to call the action of the active mode.

In this case the `base_axis` really isn't needed as the shared code for each "mode" would now be stored in each of the mode structures so you could probably just do away with inheritance all together..

```
template<class... Ts> struct overload : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overload(Ts...) -> overload<Ts...>;

struct basic_mode_1 {
    void action() { std::cout << "Basic mode step 1\n"; }
};

struct basic_mode_2 {
    void action() { std::cout << "Basic mode step 2\n"; }
};

struct ext_mode_1 {
    void action() { std::cout << "Extended mode step 1\n"; }
};

struct ext_mode_2 {
    void action() { std::cout << "Extended mode step 2\n"; }
};

template<typename ...Modes>
class base_axis {
public:
    template<typename Mode>
    void set_mode() {
        mode_ = Mode{};
    }

    virtual void run_step() = 0;
    virtual ~base_axis() = default;
protected:
    std::variant<Modes...> mode_;
};

class basic_axis : public base_axis<basic_mode_1, basic_mode_2> {
public:
    void run_step() override { 
        std::visit(overload{
            [](basic_mode_1& m) { m.action(); },
            [](basic_mode_2& m) { m.action(); }
        }, modes_);
    }
};

class ext_axis : public base_axis<basic_mode_1, basic_mode_2, ext_mode_1, ext_mode_2> {
public:
    void run_step() override { 
        std::visit(overload{
            [](basic_mode_1& m) { m.action(); },
            [](basic_mode_2& m) { m.action(); },
            [](ext_mode_1& m) { m.action(); },
            [](ext_mode_2& m) { m.action(); }
        }, modes_);
    }
};

int main() {
    ext_axis axis{};
    axis.set_mode<ext_mode_2>();
    axis.run_step();
}
```

This is how it would look without inheritance.

```
class basic_axis {
public:
    template<typename Mode>
    void set_mode() {
        mode_ = Mode{};
    }

    void run_step() { 
        std::visit(overload{
            [](basic_mode_1& m) { m.step(); },
            [](basic_mode_2& m) { m.step(); }
        }, mode_);
    }
private:
    std::variant<basic_mode_1, basic_mode_2> mode_;
};

class ext_axis {
public:
    template<typename Mode>
    void set_mode() {
        mode_ = Mode{};
    }

    void run_step() { 
        std::visit(overload{
            [](basic_mode_1& m) { m.step(); },
            [](basic_mode_2& m) { m.step(); },
            [](ext_mode_1& m) { m.step(); },
            [](ext_mode_2& m) { m.step(); }
        }, mode_);
    }
private:
    std::variant<basic_mode_1, basic_mode_2, ext_mode_1, ext_mode_2> mode_;
};
```

Comment: You don't need the inheritance at all if your `run_step` lambda looks like `[](auto &m) { m.action(); }`.

Comment: @StephenNewell Yeah I mentioned that in the last paragraph. But I kept it in there anyway.